# A function inside a function Python

Tags: python, function, printing

This is a problem asked before but I can't really understand the other explain of this kind of problem so I'm here to re-write it in more details.  While studying I have encountered this kind of code that I am not at all familiar .. I can not understand how to interpret this g() function in f() function ! Why the piece of code inside g() where x = 10 and y = z*w does not run ? It's only print me the value of y I gave, calling f() with 5 !

```
x = 99

def f(y):
    w = x + y
    def g():
        x = 10
        y = z * w
    print y

f(5)
```

Comment: `g` is never called.  Merely defining a function does not execute any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `def` is a statement: takes a function name, possibly arguments, then an indented function body -- compiles it all into a function object, which it binds to the given name in the scope where `def` appeared (here, locally to `f`).

So you ask "Why the piece of code inside g() where x = 10 and y = z*w does not run" -- very simply, because you never call `g`!

The fact that `g` is local to `f` (or as is also known "nested in `f`") is not germane.

Whether local or global, anytime you `def g` but then never call `g`, the code in `g`'s body will not execute.

Incidentally, this is a detail in which Python coincides with every other language I've ever heard about.  If a function is defined (some languages call that "declared") and **never** called, then the function's body code never runs.  Have you ever heard of any language doing otherwise -- i.e, executing the code body of a function that's defined but never called?!

Comment: mmmh ok ! And what about the 'print y' ? It's print me the value of y but it's not correctly indent ! Or maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: Ciao Roberto -- `print y` is perfectly indented exactly like the `def` statement, so it executes right after it as part of the body of `f` (since `f` **does** get called).  The indent is "incorrect" if you *meant* the `print` to be part of `g`'s body, but Python doesn't and can't read your mind regarding what you meant vs what you very clearly **said** -- it does what you clearly tell it to do, not whatever different you **meant** it to do (in this, Python's pretty much the same as any other computer program:-)

Comment: Ma prego, piacere mio!  Remember to **accept** (click the checkmark outline to the left of the answer you decide to accept) so Stackoverflow knows this Q&A is done/satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Although you define the function `g()` inside the function `f()`, you never actually call it. You'll need to make a call to it inside the `f()` function as well.

Comment: I've tried to call g() before print y ! indent as 'print y' and it gave me 0 ! I'm going crazy , can't really understand

Comment: Well, you have a `z` in the `g()` function which I don't know where it comes from. But disregarding that, you only change `y` within the scope of `g()`. If you want to do something with `y` later, you'll need to return the value and do soemthing with it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `g()` was never called inside the `f(y)` function. To properly get your code to work, it should look something like this.

```
x = 99

def f(y):
    w = x + y
    def g():
        x = 10
        y = z * w
    g(y) # <---- notice the function call for g().
    print y

f(5)
```