# How do you call a function defined in the current function by its name (a string)

Tags: python

How to call a function when it's name is stored in a string, [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string).

What I want to know is how do I do this if the function I'm wanting to call is defined in my local scope.

This differs from the other questions as they are not referring to calling a function by name when the  function is inside another function.

e.g

```
def outer():
   
    def inner():
        # code for inner

    method_to_call = 'inner'
   
    # call inner by the value of method_to_call
```

So in the above code how do I call the function defined by the value in `method_to_call`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283210/python-function-pointer

Comment: Are you *getting* the name in a string, or do you just think you need its name in a string? You can store a reference to the function in another variable: `method_to_call = inner`, then `method_to_call()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function inside a function Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400074/a-function-inside-a-function-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `locals()`:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        print("Called.")

    method_to_call = 'inner'

    locals()[method_to_call]()
```

After calling `outer`, "Called." is printed.

Note that there will be an error if there is a non-callable named `inner` (for example, having `inner = "abc"` will cause this).

However, as the comments say, this is only useful if you're getting the name `inner` from somewhere else (let's say input). If you already know what local function you want to call beforehand, it'd be better to use `inner` directly instead of through `locals()`.

Comment: By `input` you probably mean `inner`?

Comment: @fuglede Yup my bad.

Comment: locals()... Nice

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use `eval` to convert any string to code and execute it.

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        # code for inner

    method_to_call = 'inner'

    eval(method_to_call + '()')
```

Note, that the string must contain valid Python code, so in this case you would need to add parenthesis () to the name of the function, to create a call statement, as you would write it in a normal call.